# Сортировка блоков по id

Tags: jquery, сортировка

Здраствуйте.

```
<div id="result">
<div class="list" id="564">sdfdsfs</div>
<div class="list" id="5">sdfdsfs</div>
<div class="list" id="232">sdfdsfs</div>
</div>
```

Как можно отсортировать блоки по id от большего к меньшему на jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Плагин](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/) на jQuery:

```
jQuery.fn.sortElements = (function () {

    var sort = [].sort;

    return function (comparator, getSortable) {

        getSortable = getSortable ||
        function () {
            return this;
        };

        var placements = this.map(function () {

            var sortElement = getSortable.call(this),
                parentNode = sortElement.parentNode,

                // Since the element itself will change position, we have
                // to have some way of storing its original position in
                // the DOM. The easiest way is to have a 'flag' node:
                nextSibling = parentNode.insertBefore(
                document.createTextNode(''), sortElement.nextSibling);

            return function () {

                if (parentNode === this) {
                    throw new Error("You can't sort elements if any one is a descendant of another.");
                }

                // Insert before flag:
                parentNode.insertBefore(this, nextSibling);
                // Remove flag:
                parentNode.removeChild(nextSibling);

            };

        });

        return sort.call(this, comparator).each(function (i) {
            placements[i].call(getSortable.call(this));
        });

    };

})();
```

Использование:

```
$('.list').sortElements(function(a, b){
    return parseInt($(a).attr("id")) > parseInt($(b).attr("id")) ? 1 : -1;
});
```